# How can I get an index of my View from Scroll View in Panresponder onMove callback (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently having a scrollview which has some childview components. I have added a panresponder to the scrollview as well. As I start dragging inside the scrollview, the child view components has to change color.

I am trying to get the index of View from the scrollview on the panresponder onMove callback so that using the index of that view, I can change the color of the respective view. How can I do that in react native?

Check this link for example for what I am trying to achieve.
http://pablofierro.github.io/react-drag-select

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Progress made so far:
I need the Gesture View index on the panresponder onMove callback

```
<ScrollView
  {...this.state.isLongTapped === true ? 
  {...this._panResponder.panHandlers } : null}>
              {dates.map(date => {
                return (
                  <View key={date} style={styles.rowContainer}>
                      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                        {this.state.times.map((time, index) => {
                          containerStyle = object;
                          timeData = [];
                          let scheduleIndex = 0;
                          if (isCurrentBoard) {
                            let schedule = time.schedules;
                            if (schedule) {
                              scheduleIndex = this.getColumnIndexForDate(date.toString());
                              timeData.push(schedule[scheduleIndex])
                            }
                          }
                          return (
                            <GestureView
                              gestureCallBack={this.gestureSelectSchedule}>
                            </GestureView>
                          );
                        })}
                      </View>
                  </View>)
              })}
            </ScrollView>
```

```
  gestureSelectSchedule = () => {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: (event,gestureState) => {

      },
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {      
      },
      onPanResponderEnd: (e, gestureState) => {

      }
    });
    this.setState({ isLongTapped: true });
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you made so far?

Comment: @WiliamBrochensquejunior edited and added code for reference. Please check